# How to set import location to use the same host (http header) of the client request

Tags: wcf, wsdl

I want to deploy a WCF Web service, but to be perfect, WSDL must be accessed from any computer, from LAN and WAN.

The problem is that when local lan ip is used, WAN users accessing through the public IP can't download references (import) because the WDSL uses the local ip in the URL.

So, it is very frustrating because the correct way is that WSDL generator uses the "host" HTTP Header for includes in order to work in any situation (local lan ip, public ip) because this is the way that client see the resource

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can control what URLs are published within the WSDL by a WCF service if you set the `httpGetUrl` attribute of the `serviceMetadata` element as [documented here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.servicemetadatabehavior.httpgeturl%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for WCF starting with version 3.5. If you set an absolute address to use the DNS registered host name, then all your clients will be able to access it.

In some situations (such as load balanced servers), you may also need to [set the `useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.configuration.userequestheadersformetadataaddresselement%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which is a WCF version 4.0 and later feature.